# Using precomputed Gram matrix in sklearn linear models (Lasso, Lars, etc)

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm trying to train a linear model on a very large dataset. 
The feature space is small but there are too many samples to hold in memory. 
I'm calculating the Gram matrix on-the-fly and trying to pass it as an argument to sklearn Lasso (or other algorithms) but, when I call fit, it needs the actual X and y matrices.

Any idea how to use the 'precompute' feature without storing the original matrices?

Answer (score 0):

(My answer is based on the usage of svm.SVC, Lasso may be different.)

I think that you are supposed pass the Gram matrix instead of X to the fit method.

Also, the Gram matrix has shape (n_samples, n_samples) so it should also be too large for memory in your case, right?

Comment: Thanks.. I looked at the source code and it uses the shape of the X matrix to get the number of samples, so giving the Gram matrix will not do the trick (it might work, but will give different results). The Gram matrix is not too large because I have many samples but only about a 1000 features.

Comment: For clarity in case someone reads this: Gram matrix has shape nFeatures, nFeatures; not nSamples, nSamples